# SQL to Concat strings and then remove blank spaces

Tags: sql, sql-server, string

I am trying to work out how to concat multiple fields, removing any spaces between them and then comparing them to another value.

I have the following fields : Address1, Town, County & Postcode. 
Basically i need these strings concatenated and then removing any white space etc. Can someone please show me how i would do this within my the following sql i have here:

```
select distinct p.GtId,
    p.CrmPartyId,
    p.LegalName,
    p.BusinessClass,
    p.RmFullName,
    p.PbeFullName,
    p.OverallClientStatus,
    p.OverallRpStatus,
   a.AddressType
from CORE.WeccoParty p
    join CORE.WeccoPartyAddress a ON p.GtId = a.GtId
where exists (select 1
           from CORE.WeccoParty sub_p
           left join CORE.WeccoPartyAddress sub_a 
             on sub_p.GtId = sub_a.GtId 
           where (p.FirstName     =  sub_p.FirstName
                  and p.LastName  =  sub_p.LastName
                  and a.Address1=  sub_a.Address1
                  and a.Town = sub_a.Town
                  and a.County = sub_a.County
                  and a.Postcode = sub_a.Postcode
                  and a.GtId           <> sub_a.GtId)
          )
```

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Why not stick to the field by field comparison you are performing already?

Comment: To concatenate and after replace spaces you can use `replace(concat(a.Address1, a.Town, a.County, a.Postcode), ' ', '')`, but I do not understand what is the goal of such kind of concatenation, could you explain the task more detailed

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Could you please [edit] your question to make it a bit more understandable? See [ask] for information on how to properly ask a question. Help us help you!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select distinct Replace(p.GtId+
    p.CrmPartyId+
    p.LegalName+
    p.BusinessClass+
    p.RmFullName+
    p.PbeFullName+
    p.OverallClientStatus+
    p.OverallRpStatus+
   a.AddressType,' ','')
   from CORE.WeccoParty p
   join CORE.WeccoPartyAddress a ON p.GtId = a.GtId
   where exists (select 1
           from CORE.WeccoParty sub_p
           left join CORE.WeccoPartyAddress sub_a 
             on sub_p.GtId = sub_a.GtId 
           where (p.FirstName     =  sub_p.FirstName
                  and p.LastName  =  sub_p.LastName
                  and a.Address1=  sub_a.Address1
                  and a.Town = sub_a.Town
                  and a.County = sub_a.County
                  and a.Postcode = sub_a.Postcode
                  and a.GtId           <> sub_a.GtId)
          )
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Great to see you answering questions. Could you also add some explanation about your answer (What does it do?) so users can learn from it?

Comment: Note that OP needs 4 specific columns concatenated, not all columns from the outer SELECT. I suspect (from their names) that it is needed in the inner SELECT or WHERE.

Comment: Could you please explain further, Peter? I am sorry i do not understand

Answer (score 0):

You can use [REPLACE](https://www.techonthenet.com/sql_server/functions/replace.php) & [CONCAT](https://www.techonthenet.com/sql_server/functions/concat.php) function in SQL Server.

> CONCAT function works from SQL Server 2012 & above, if you are using older version use "**+**" operator to concatenate.

You can also check [LTRIM](https://www.techonthenet.com/sql_server/functions/ltrim.php) & [RTRIM](https://www.techonthenet.com/sql_server/functions/rtrim.php) Function if that's your Requirement for removing spaces at the starting & ending of Strings

```
select distinct p.GtId,
    p.CrmPartyId,
    p.LegalName,
    p.BusinessClass,
    p.RmFullName,
    p.PbeFullName,
    p.OverallClientStatus,
    p.OverallRpStatus,
   a.AddressType
from CORE.WeccoParty p
    join CORE.WeccoPartyAddress a ON p.GtId = a.GtId
where exists (select 1
           from CORE.WeccoParty sub_p
           left join CORE.WeccoPartyAddress sub_a 
             on sub_p.GtId = sub_a.GtId 
           where (p.FirstName     =  sub_p.FirstName
                  and p.LastName  =  sub_p.LastName
                  and REPLACE(CONCAT(a.Address1,a.Town,a.County,a.Postcode),' ','') = REPLACE(CONCAT(sub_a.Address1, sub_a.Town,sub_a.County,sub_a.Postcode),' ','')
                  and a.GtId           <> sub_a.GtId)
          )
```

Comment: Note that OP needs 4 specific columns concatenated, not all columns from the outer SELECT. I suspect (from their names) that it is needed in the inner SELECT or WHERE.

Comment: Edited the Query

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to StackOverflow! It looks like by your tags that you are using SQL server.
Assuming that you are, you can use the following two functions to help accomplish your goal: 

REPLACE: https://www.techonthenet.com/sql_server/functions/replace.php 
CONCAT: https://www.techonthenet.com/sql_server/functions/concat.php

The REPLACE function would simply replace a space, denoted by ' ', with nothing, denoted by ''. 
The CONCAT function would then concatenate them together.

If I am looking at your SQL Code and trying to concatenate Address1, Town, County & Postcode, per your description, AND keeping everything you have currently, I would probably do something like this:

```
select distinct p.GtId,
    p.CrmPartyId,
    p.LegalName,
    p.BusinessClass,
    p.RmFullName,
    p.PbeFullName,
    p.OverallClientStatus,
    p.OverallRpStatus,
   a.AddressType,
   REPLACE(CONCAT(a.Address1, a.Town, a.County, a.Postcode), ' ', '')
from CORE.WeccoParty p
    join CORE.WeccoPartyAddress a ON p.GtId = a.GtId
where exists (select 1
           from CORE.WeccoParty sub_p
           left join CORE.WeccoPartyAddress sub_a 
             on sub_p.GtId = sub_a.GtId 
           where (p.FirstName     =  sub_p.FirstName
                  and p.LastName  =  sub_p.LastName
                  and a.Address1=  sub_a.Address1
                  and a.Town = sub_a.Town
                  and a.County = sub_a.County
                  and a.Postcode = sub_a.Postcode
                  and a.GtId           <> sub_a.GtId)
          )
```

The line that I added was: 
 **`REPLACE(CONCAT(a.Address1, a.Town, a.County, a.Postcode), ' ', '')`**

That line should REPLACE ' ' (a space) with '' (nothing) in the CONCATENATED STRING of those columns.

Let me know if this answers your question, or how else I can help.

Comment: Thanks very much. Excellent response.

Comment: No problem, @K1205. If this was the solution, do us a favor and mark it as such :) That way other people can be helped by your question, too!